# Typescript. Check if method/property exists in the variable of unknown type

Tags: javascript, typescript

TS v3.x brought new type: `unknown`. But it's not very clear how to easily use this type instead of `any`.
Example: you're using some 3rd party library which has no types. And you don't have time to write those types yourself. You need to handle some data provided by that library.

Before `unknown`:

```
function handle(data: any) {
   if (data && data.arrayProp && typeof data.arrayProp[Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
       for (let x of data.arrayProp) {...}
   }
}
```

With `unknown`:

```
function handle(data: unknown) {
   // this line gives TS error: `data` is unknown type
   if (data && data.arrayProp && typeof data.arrayProp[Symbol.iterator]=== 'function') {  
...
```

Most docs in internet are using kind of `instanceof` ways to check what type `data` has. But i'm not really interested what type `data` has. Everything i want to know is if there's `arrayProp` there. that's it

How to do this with `unknown` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing with `unknown` is that you have to narrow its type before you can use it. You can use a custom type guard for this:

```
interface ArrayProp {
  arrayProp: []
}
function isArrayProps(value: unknown): value is ArrayProp {
  return !!value && !!(value as ArrayProp).arrayProp;
}

function handle(data: unknown) {
   if (isArrayProps(data) && typeof data.arrayProp[Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
   }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngBSgewAdkBvAKGWTg2zyIC5kBtAXTIF8yYBXEBMYPhDJgAZ3SZcBQqIAUANzgAbbhEa8A1iHwB3EAEpGilSjFoaUoqQrIoEMNyjCAhM+OrkAMk-JXC5R5wouaSdIT6AHTUodIA3BxkXLz8gsIAFnAgACZKELJZcGBw6iBaugbWlCIwyLJiErTScgVF+l4+YFiEEPg1LXBRFmFMAMpYALYARvhKEcCQmGD4UCzIALwbyADkPHwCQltt5FWc7EA)

Comment: Thank you. So, in run time it will be equivalent code as in my samples. why then not to allow it to compile... most probably i stick to `any` type for now, too much boilerplate with `unknown` type IMO :-)

Comment: You are right. At runtime it will be pretty much the same. But I would still prefer the Typescript (boilerplate) way. The reason is that outside the `if` you are secure. You can't call `data.blab` or `data.foo` or even `data.arrayProp` again. By forcing you to add the boilerplate Typescript is forcing you to be very thoughtful about the way you will be accessing that `unknown`.

Comment: I'd love to use `unknown`. Boilerplate is not the most problematic thing about it. The thing is i don't get why not to allow to compile my second sample? i did all the checks which are necessary for code inside `if` block. And outside of `if` block you're still safe. I.e. i see no value in this boilerplate...